# Dictionary/hash_map key size

Tags: c#, c++, data-structures

The hash value for key is caculated and is divided by a prime number. 
In general, Is there any standard prime number (say for 32/64 bit) for this?

My understanding is the hashtable is not resizable/adjustable and its internal array depends on this. If I have a hashtable for only 5 elements will there be waste in key space?

Edit: I should have framed this better. What is general approach followed in c++ hash_map (boost) or C# Dictionary

Comment: If you only have 5 elements, why use a hash table at all?

Comment: So you never use a Dictionary with 5 elements? Question is why not? That is a hypothetical question. Alternatively, What border number do you suggest?

Comment: I suppose I've created a dictionary that ended up holding only five elements.  I would allocate it at a larger size, though, (probably more than 10) to reduce the chance of collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, hash tables sizes can be adjustable automatically. What you might do is allocate an array of size N, using a hash modulo N (some prime number) for indexing into the array. If you keep track of the density of your allocation, then when it increases beyond some threshold you can allocate a new array of size N1 (some larger prime number), and copy over each element from the old array, applying the hash function with the *new* modulo to find its place in the new hash table. Finally you deallocate the old array and use the new, larger array.

Comment: Thanks! I should have framed this better. What is general approach followed in c++ hash_map (boost) or C# Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Often, the prime number is used as the size of the internal array.  That is, if somebody asks for a hash table of 100 items, you pick the next prime that's >= 100 and that's the size.  In that case, you'd have a table size of 101.

But that's not the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Reflector to see C# Dictionary or HashTable implementations? Both answers by Greg and Jim are correct speaking in general terms and for C# implementation.

In summary, C# Dictionary implementation uses a prime number (that is greater than its capacity) as a size of internal bucket array and uses it for dividing the hash code. Whenever, there is need to resize internal array, it uses twice the existing capacity as a new capacity.